# CSS hover Only Works On The Top Half of My Button

Tags: html, css, button, web, hover

I'm really pulling my hair out on this one. I don't do webpages professionally or on a regular basis; and I'm really stumped.

You can go to my work-in-progress page here:

http://damienivan.com/wip/042/

If you hover over one of the buttons below "featured work," the hover state and "link finger" only appear if your cursor is over the top half of the button.

The CSS is:

```
    .work_button    
        {
        width:              174px;
        height:             58px;
        float:              left;
        background:         #3FC0E9;
        border-right:       4px solid #30A9D0;
        }

    .work_button:hover
        {
        background:         #FFF;
        color:              #30A9D0;
        }
```

The HTML is:

```
<a href="demo_reel.html" target="video_player">
    <div class="work_button">
        <h2>demo reel</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

The full CSS file is at:

http://damienivan.com/wip/stylesheets/main.css

Thanks in advance! I'm really stuck here.

-Damien

Comment: If you have such problems you should first check the dev tools of the browser. There you e.g. have a tool that shows you the element that is under the current mouse position and there you can see that your `footer` is overlaying the menu.

Comment: Oh geez, now I feel really dumb! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your #work_wrapper div has a fixed height (bad idea). Remove that height, and instead set it to `overflow: hidden` so that it wraps around your buttons:

```
#work_wrapper {
width: 890px;
height: 100px;    /*  REMOVE THIS  */
padding-top: 14px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;  /*  ADD THIS  */
}
```

Also, you shouldn't really be using a `div` and `h2` inside your links. Strip them out, and do this instead:

HTML:

```
<a href="demo_reel.html" target="video_player">demo reel</a>
```

CSS:

```
#work_button_wrapper a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 174px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 58px;
  background: #3FC0E9;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

#work_button_wrapper a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #3FC0E9;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to increase height of your `work_wrapper`. Try this:

```
#work_wrapper {
    height: 125px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    position: relative;
    width: 890px;
}
```

Or, you can also try this:

```
#footer_wrapper { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Perfect Answer, what i am searching for

Comment: @Romancha worst solution because it does not remove the initial problem.

Comment: it solves the problem, may be in static manner but it solves.

Comment: Increasing thei height is not a good idea. Don't use height at all, but `overflow: hidden` (see my answer).

Comment: there was height on first place and i gave a quick fix btw @ralph.m your answer is cool

Comment: Oh man, that was really simple and obvious. I guess that's what I get for working til 4am. Thank you so much! And yes, increasing the size of the #work_wrapper totally works in my case, since that's what it should be doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This css statement can help you:

```
 #footer_wrapper { clear: both; }
```

BTW: Nesting a div into an anchor tag ist not valid.

Comment: For the given `doctype` you are right, but with html5 it is valid to put a `div` inside an `a`

Comment: True! Thanks for the addition. (But I guess only for a tag?)

Comment: @t.niese can you please give a link to prove your statement? I see no reason why they should change the mechanics to disallow block elements inside inline-elements.

Comment: @Christoph it is not _inline_ anymore but _transparent_ http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html _Changes in HTML5_ [...] an instance of the `a` element is now allowed to also contain _flow_ content (essentially, what was in previous versions referred to as _“block”_ content) — if the parent element of that instance of the a element is an element that is allowed to contain _flow_ content. [...]

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the link. However flow content != block elements. I find the html5 distinction rather unintuitive. Basically block element would be flow - phrasing content... -_-

Comment: @Wipster `del` and `ins` count also to _transparent content_.  But to be honest i don't know a complete list neither i can find one on w3c.

Comment: @t.niese Here maybe one: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing

Comment: I didn't realize that nesting a div in an a was invalid. I'll try fixing that.

Comment: Or just use HTML5 Doctype :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox to debug your web-page. Both browsers have an option to use the webdeveloper tools, which will allow you to visualize the CSS better. This will help you actually see what is happening, and in this case, there is a cssobject blocking half of your button.
A great plus in this in Firefox is that it has a 3D-view option. It looks geeky at first, but it can be REALLY helpful when trying to view what is going on in the CSS.

Comment: With Firefox I'd recommend the Firebug extension over the builtin webdev tools.

Comment: Most definitely!!! The Firebug extension is indeed a great tool that you just have to install! But the 3D option that I mentioned here is not a part of Firebug, but of Firefox itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view

Comment: Didn't know of that one. This might come in handy. Alas, my graphics card seems to not be capable.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, thank you. Normally I do this, I guess I just wasn't thinking straight lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the footer of your page.
It's above the buttons.

Give the buttons a z-index and it will work great!

You can always give your footer a `z-index:-1;`

Buttons will be shown on top and have a hover on the whole button

Answer (score 0):

You're mixin inline and block elements. Inspect the H2 and you see the clickable elements ends there.

[image]

Refactored HTML below:

```
<div id="work_button_wrapper">

    <a href="demo_reel.html" class="work_button" target="video_player">            
            demo reel           
    </a>

    <a href="hp.html" class="work_button" target="video_player">          
            hp            
    </a>

    <a href="free_world.html" class="work_button" target="video_player">    
            free world          
    </a>

    <a class="work_button" href="dabo.html" target="video_player">           
            dabo            
    </a>

    <a class="work_button" href="sugar_skull.html" target="video_player" class="work_button work_button_last">           
            sugar skull          
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font: 17px/19px Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}

#work_button_wrapper
    {
    width:              890px;
    float:              left;
    padding-top:        9px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.work_button    
    {
    width:              174px;
    float:              left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:         #3FC0E9;
    border-right:       4px solid #30A9D0;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: normal;
        letter-spacing: -1.5px;
        text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 10px;
}

.work_button:hover
    {
    background:         #FFF;
    color:              #30A9D0;
    }

.work_button_last
    {
    width:              178px;
    border-right:       0px solid #30A9D0;;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brutusmaximus/ZPunN/

Answer (score 0):

Move `a tag` inside the `div` and add width and height for a tag (Already you are giving `height and width` for the div which is covering the a tag so there is no wrong in giving the same `height` and `width` to the `a tag`)

```
#work_button_wrapper
        {
        width:              890px;
        float:              left;
        padding-top:        9px;
        /* border:              2px solid #FFF; */
        }

    .work_button    
        {
        width:              174px;
        height:             58px;
        float:              left;
        background:         #3FC0E9;
        border-right:       4px solid #30A9D0;
  text-align:center
        }
    .work_button a
        {
        text-decoration:    none;
        font-size:          15px;
        color:              #FFF;
        height:58px;
        width:174px
}
h2{
  height:100%; width:100%
}
    .work_button a:hover
        {
        background:         #FFF;
        color:              #30A9D0;
        }

    .work_button_last
        {
        width:              178px;
        border-right:       0px solid #30A9D0;;
        }   


#work_button_wrapper a:hover
        {
        /* background:          #3FC0E9; */
        background:         #FFF;
        color:              #30A9D0;
        }
.work_button:hover
        {
        background:         #FFF;
        color:              #30A9D0;
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jy87L/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.  For me a parent div had position:fixed and was invisibly above the button, which was difficult to pinpoint.